# How to validate negative values in query

Tags: postgresql, query, pgadmin

Hi I am using postgresql in my project. I want to make a validation that if query returns negative then i want to change output to null.

```
(to_char (NULLIF(coalesce(0::numeric,0) - 
(coalesce(26776.94::numeric,0) - 
(coalesce(2760::numeric,0) + (coalesce(1800::numeric,0)))),0)::numeric/3600,'FM99,999,999,999.00'))::character varying as clds
```

it is giving -6.17 as output , I want to make it null

Comment: Why are you trying to treat `NUMERIC`s as `VARCHAR`s?

Comment: @Vérace is GREATEST good approach ?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
CASE
  LEFT
  (
    to_char (NULLIF(coalesce(0::numeric,0) - 
    (coalesce(26776.94::numeric,0) - 
    (coalesce(2760::numeric,0) + 
   (coalesce(1800::numeric,0)))),0)::numeric/3600,'FM99,999,999,999.00'))::VARCHAR
    ,1                -- <<<---- the '1' gets the minus sign from the string!
  )
  = '-' THEN NULL
  ELSE 
    to_char (NULLIF(coalesce(0::numeric,0) - 
    (coalesce(26776.94::numeric,0) - 
    (coalesce(2760::numeric,0) + 
    (coalesce(1800::numeric,0)))),0)::numeric/3600,'FM99,999,999,999.00'))::VARCHAR
END AS clds
```

I have to say though that this has to be one of **the** most horrible SQL constructs that I've **ever** seen!

I would give **serious** consideration to devoting some (lots?) of effort towards an in-depth refactoring!

Comment: I tried with GREATEST , is it good approach ?

Comment: @humbertoherrara - I'm afraid that I don't exactly understand where `GREATEST` could be of use here - maybe you could expand on that in the question and leave a comment for me (using @Vérace) so that I can see what you're driving at?